# serving multiple model version in springboot app - best approach

Tags: spring-boot, architecture, software-design

My application is based on some api, which has multiple versions. For example

- v1: User (name : String, surname: String)
- v2: User (name : String, surname: String, middleName: String)
  Is there a better solution than creating another POJO class for each version and creating another set of controllers, services etc.

Can someone give me a clue what i should look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my point of view, the best approach would be to have a versioned context path. Something like the following endpoints:

- *your-domain*/v1/...
- *your-domain*/v2/...

This means you would have at least 2 different Controllers (one for each version) and 2 different models. At some point in the future, you could simply drop one of them if you want to stick with one and your consumers have migrated to the other.

This is true if the differences between the models v1 and v2 are big. If they are not that many or if they are not that complex you might want to take a look at [JSON Views](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation).

Comment: That is bad news, but I thought that. But I had hope, that someone give me some light.

Comment: Are the differences between models v1 and v2 that many or JSON Views could help?

Comment: I haven’t heard about json views, are you talking about this https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation

Comment: Yes, I had the link in my answer. Basically, you can stick with the same model and use `@JsonView` annotation in your model to select the attributes to include in a given view.

Comment: Tkank you very much! I think that this what i was looking for

Comment: Great! Glad I could help! ;)